# Is it possible to print one artboard, multiple times, on the same page in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I've one illustrator file. The artboard takes much less than 1/4 of an A4 page. I would like to print 80 copies of it, 4 on each page. Is it possible?

I know that I can export the image, then ask windows to print them 4 by page, but I will loose illustrators options(trim marks by example).

So, is this possible with illustrator? What is the best way to do it? In the future I will have to do this regularly.

Comment: I have been trying to achieve the same, without having to resort to things like duplicating the artwork manually and such. I resorted to Corel DRAW and managed to achieve the [wanted result](https://imgur.com/a/yC9reH7) in like 5 minutes using imposition tools... Now, I strongly prefer AI to CD, but here AI (and InDesign, Acrobat, etc. for that matter) let me down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **Symbols**.

Group your current artboard. 
Choose `Effect > Crop Marks` to add crops to it. (or manually add marks, which is what I would do)
Drag it all to the **Symbols Panel** to create a symbol of your artwork with the marks.

Create a new A4 artboard...

Place as many of the *Symbol instances* as you like on the A4 artboard. They'll all have crops.

Print the A4 artboard.

If you need to edit the original, double-click the Symbol in the Symbols Panel to edit it. One symbol, used as many times as you like. This won't increase file size and allows you to control the layout of the "multi-up" page.

Comment: Such a great workflow - nice recommendation!

Answer (score 0):

That's my print dialog with the set up to 4 pages per sheet.

Click the Setup button to bring that second panel.

It is in Portuguese but I think it's easy to figure it out in other languages:

[image]

Comment: What did you click on to have this second popup? I don't see it anywhere? Is it something directly related to your  printer?

Comment: I forgot to mention. I clicked the "Setup" button. My printer is a Laser printer (Kyocera).

Comment: Okay, but I think it's dedicated to your printer, will not work for me :(

Comment: In fact, that Setup tab shown in this answer is managed ***not*** by the *printer*, *but by the* ***OS*** - which in this answer's case is **Mac OS** - you *don't have* that OS-level setup option available in **Windows** - it has to come from the devices' driver in Windows. If you don't have it, you don't have it!